# How to join multiple tables

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I'm trying to join multiple tables in q

```
        a                  b                  c
    key | valuea       key | valueb       key | valuec
     1  |   xa          1  |   xb          2  |   xc
     2  |   ya          2  |   yb          4  |   wc
     3  |   za
```

The expected result is

```
    key | valuea | valueb | valuec
     1  |   xa   |    xb  |   
     2  |   ya   |    yb  |   xc
     3  |   za   |        |   
     4  |        |        |   wc
```

The can be acheieved simply with

```
    (a uj b) uj c
```

BUT does anyone know how i can do it in functional form?
I don't know how many tables i actually have

I need basically a function that will go over the list and smash any number of keyed tables together...

```
f:{[x] x uj priorx};
f[] each (a;b;c;d;e...)
```

Can anyone help? or suggest anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution particular to your problem which is also little faster than your solution:

a (,')/(b;c)

Answer (score 1):

figured it out... ;)

```
f:{[r;t]r uj t};
f/[();(a;b;c)]
```

Comment: Another way of writing it is :                                        () uj/(a;b;c)

Comment: you could further simplify by making `uj` monadic: `(uj/)(a;b;c)` or `uj/[(a;b;c)]` will both do the trick