# Multiple union joins in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a task in which I need to do Union Joins of variable no. of tables. As of now, I've stored all the tables in a list.

How can I do a multiple union joins of all the tables using adverb ?

Example:

```
L:(table1,table2,table3)
// I need something like (2!table1) uj (2!table2) uj (2!table3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197779/how-to-join-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is already answered here:

[How to join multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197779/how-to-join-multiple-tables)

```
q)a:([]a:1 2;b:3 4)
q)b:([]a:1 2;c:5 6)
q)(uj/)1!'(a;b)
a| b c
-| ---
1| 3 5
2| 4 6
```